# Size limit of a string passed to function as a parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a function with one parameter like : function(a){/*do something*/}

if I pass a string to the function then is there any size limit of string which I can pass?

Comment: How big of a string do you want to pass?!

Comment: The user's patience with the application's speed (or slowness) is the limit.

Comment: Actually I am passing a xml and I am not sure about the size of xml, so I am afraid about the size limit of the sting parameter. And other concern about the perfomance, does size affect the speed?

Comment: I am seeing a truncation at about 65k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not defined in the standard ==> implementation dependant.

[A cool resource.](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/92088-max-allowed-length-javascript-string) Cool because Crockford is the first response, and the rest of the discussion quotes other known names in the JS world.

As clarification, the limit is not going to be on the string size *you can pass* to the function, but just a limit on the string size *that the language supports*. I.e. if you have no concerns about the size of the string in one place, then passing it is fine.

Comment: @skgyan, not in the sense you're asking. Since javascript is pass-by-value with references, passing a string won't rebuild the string, but rather copy the reference and assign/bind to the new variable name. That means that passing a string will take exactly the same time no matter what size the string is (cache and other negligible issues aside.)

Answer (score -2):

Passing by reference is always a great strategy. Passing the URI of the data resource (basically the pointer to the head of a list), dividing the data in chunks and retrieving / GET-ing the nodes in a linked list should be a good approach (look at CORS).

Comment: What do CORS and URIs of data resources have to do with the question?